# Testing a single unit test case with many fixtures / scenarios in Pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fixtures

I have a class that represents a certain complex state. That state can change, and I I have another instance of that class that represents the "true" state. I wrote a function that does some diffing logic and figures out how to get the current state to the true state, if they differ.

I'd like to test that function using `pytest`. There are many scenarios possibilities, but the test logic is pretty simple and boils down to (pseudo python code):

```
def test_diffing(current_state, prescribed_state):
    properties_to_add = []
    properties_to_delete = []
    properties_to_modify = []
    properties_to_add, properties_to_delete, properties_to_modify = diff_logic(current_state, prescribed_state)

    assert properties_to_add == 1
    assert properties_to_delete == 0
    assert properties_to_modify == 3
```

The numbers on the right hand side of the assert depend on what the `current_state` is. I have many `current_state` scenarios.

What is the best way to write a single unit test as above, with many pairs of fixtures such that the current_state is passed along with the expected values of the asserts?

I have looked at pytest fixtures parametrization but the problem with this approach is that it's using decorators and that gets ugly* very quickly, especially with a large number of arguments and large number of test cases. It seems that this is not what I should be using fixtures for.

What's the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do cleanly?

**I am saying it gets ugly because having 15 or 20 sets of arguments to a decorator is very confusing and puts a lot of logic in the decorator itself.*

Comment: If my understanding is correct, fixtures are more for commonality between tests, not for varying input. In your case, you're probably better off writing 15-20 unit tests if you're testing 15-20 unique scenarios.

Comment: That makes sense. What's the best way to avoid duplicating the same exact logic 15-20 times though? The only difference is the current_state object along with its expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [parametrized fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize) to get at what you want.

How about something like:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[
    {
        'current_state': 'foo',
        'expected': {
            'properties_to_add': 1,
            'properties_to_delete': 2,
            'properties_to_modify': 3,
        },
    },
    ... as many scenarios as you'd like ...
])
def bundle(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def current_state(bundle):
    return bundle['current_state']

@pytest.fixture
def expected(bundle):
    return bundle['expected']
```

I use the "bundle" fixture construct to tie together the inputs and the outputs. Then the test looks very clean:

```
def test_diffing(current_state, expected):
    prescribed_state = ...  # I assume this is a constant, you can inject "prescribed_state" in the fixture in the same way as "current_state" and "expected"
    properties_to_add, properties_to_delete, properties_to_modify = diff_logic(current_state, prescribed_state)
    assert expected == {
        'properties_to_add': properties_to_add,
        'properties_to_delete': properties_to_delete,
        'properties_to_modify': properties_to_modify,
    }
```

Then if the "params" data structure (for the "bundle" fixture) gets very large, you can define it somewhere else and format the code for readability, load it from a data file, etc.